# What's the best way to get Python 2.5 and 2.7

Tags: python, software-installation

Ubuntu 10.04 has only two supported Python versions 2.6 and 3.1.  Developers often need more, to test that their Python code works on 2.7, 2.5 (and maybe even 2.4 and older ones).  What's the best way to install those Python versions side-by-side on a lucid system?

Is it [Felix Krull's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/deadsnakes), which I'm currently using?

Incidentally, some important packages aren't available in those non-standard Pythons from the deadsnakes PPA:

- python-setuptools (but you can install python-setuptools-deadsnakes)
- python-profiler

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I also use the fkrull's Deadsnakes PPA. I think it is the best way to get Python 2.4, 2.5, and 2.7 at this time. I have not run into any problems using it alongside the default Python2.6. It also helps to keep things clean if you use a [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv), especially for those versions of Python that are not the system default.

Comment: +1 for PPA + virtualenv. I've expanded upon this approach in a similar question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/17841/will-python2-7-be-available-for-lucid-in-future/26002#26002

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet would probably be using `debootstrap` to create a chroot of an earlier Ubuntu version where 2.5 was supported, or use a virtual machine.

Installing it in Ubuntu alongside 2.6 may cause problems.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the problems that may cause?

Comment: Some libraries are incorrectly marked as supporting 'all' Python versions when they only support 2.6.x. They will break in interesting and hard-to-debug ways.