# Installing Python 2.4 for development?

Tags: 10.10, python

I have a VM of Ubuntu 10.10 x86, and I need to build a Mercurial installation against Python 2.4. I have to do this because the web host I am working on has Python 2.4 as the latest copy of Python.

In Ubuntu 9.10 it was a simple as editing two make files to target the `python2.4` executable, and doing a `make local` against it. However since Ubuntu 10.10 does not have 2.4 I need to install the base, libraries, and dev tools for 2.4.

How do I go about doing this? I wasn't able to find a good walk-through via Google.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find python 2.4 and 2.5 in this PPA https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/deadsnakes

I am successfully using the python2.5 from this PPA, but I have not tested the python2.4 packages.

[This is a similar question.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4967/whats-the-best-way-to-get-python-2-5-and-2-7-on-ubuntu-10-04)

Comment: You can also get Python 2.5 and 2.7 from that PPA.

Comment: That PPA provides python2.7 only for Lucid. python2.7 should be by default in Maverick.

Comment: Oh man it was a simple as installing `python2.4 python2.4-dev` on to my VM. Thanks a bunch man :)