# Installing Python 3.8 alongside the base system installation

Tags: software-installation, python

I'm on Ubuntu Mate 20.04. I'd like to install latest Python 3.8 on my system globally but I've noticed that it's the same Python install that is managed by the OS and therefore I'd like not to tweak it. For various reasons I need to work with exactly 3.8. I was thinking about installing it locally (e.g. on `$HOME/.local`) or even create a `venv` and sourcing the activation on every prompt but it seems to be just more confusing. Is there a safer way to achieve this?

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226145/how-to-use-multiple-python-versions-on-the-same-system) is not really the answer I was looking for. I'm talking about installing the same python version used by the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'global' is a broad term.
The system-wide installation that comes pre-packaged with ubuntu is located in the `/usr/bin/` directory.

If you want to install the latest python version, one of the best ways is to install it from the source (with sudo). This way, it will be installed 'globally' but at the `/usr/local/bin` directory.

Now, you will have two versions of the python interpreter - it's possible to have both of them as python3.8.

However, they remain distinct. One of them can be mapped as the default system-wide interpreter by using `update-alternatives`.

Comment: I'll try this approach! Would it make any difference using `make altinstall` instead of `make install`?

Comment: I would prefer `make altinstall` to `make install`, and then use `update-alternatives` to create the symbolic links. Here is link that discusses on it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16018463/difference-in-details-between-make-install-and-make-altinstall

Comment: A further note, `update-alternatives` can be used to create custom commands as well (ex: https://documentation.suse.com/sles/15-SP1/html/SLES-all/cha-update-alternative.html#sec-ua-install),. So, to prevent mixup with the core facilities of linux (as linux does a heavy usage of python), I would use `update-alternatives` to create a custom command  say py3.8cust and set priorities to the various python interpreters. This way, it remains global and not tied to any specific user's home directory, but does not interfer with the operations of the host OS.

Comment: DONT EVER update alternatives for "python" or change the "python" or "python3" symbolic links on Ubuntu. It will corrupt your Ubuntu. You will start getting Your python install is corrupted. Please fix the '/usr/bin/python' symlink errors.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @ArnabDe, you can install any version from source in `/usr/local` and have it separated from the system interpreter.

However given your requirements, I think [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) is what you're looking for.

It let's you install any version you want and use it the default interpreter **for your user only**. I would especially advise against the `update-alternatives` part of the other answer as Ubuntu heavily relies on python and modifying the default system interpreter is likely to break *a lot* of things.

Comment: I'm aware of `pyenv` but I'd prefer to avoid it. I recently read an [interesting topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47559925/4442337) about all these tools and [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573587/what-is-the-difference-between-venv-pyvenv-pyenv-virtualenv-virtualenvwrappe#comment111446302_47559925) was especially pertinent.

Comment: Anyhow I tend to agree on the usage of `update-alternatives` on this end. After the source file installation I've obtained a fresh `python3.8` which substituted the system one (`/usr/bin`) and I'm totally fine with it. I don't think it can break anything since system calls should use absolute paths referring to binaries (e.g. `/usr/bin/python3`). But that's just supposition so I'm open for any denial.